# Discord bot let a specific user read channel

Tags: python, discord

I am trying to make a tickets feature on my discord bot
It should create a new channel that allows the user and moderators to read the channel

```
@client.command()
async def ticket(ctx, *, reason):
    username = ctx.message.author.name
    username1  = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    username2 = "<@" + username1 + ">"
    name = "tickets"
    category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name=name)
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    channel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(username, category=category)
    await message.channel.set_permissions(message.author, read_messages=True,send_messages=True, overwrite=True)
    await channel.send("Ticket send by: " + username2 + "\n" + "``" + reason + "``")
```

How would I allow just that specific user to view the new channel created.

Comment: What's the issue you're running into with your current code?

Comment: `await message.channel.set_permissions(message.author, read_messages=True,send_messages=True, overwrite=True)` It just doesn't do anything with the permissions. Nothing happens.